# R - devtools - Build - ZIP failure?

Tags: r, zip, devtools

I have been trying to build a package in R using the package devtools and the build function but it keeps failing on the zip element despite having the zip package installed?

```
* installing to library 
'C:/Users/OMICRON/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpc30Top/temp_libpath133c19a632ea'
* installing *source* package 'simTools' ...
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
converting help for package 'simTools'
finding HTML links ... done
sampleFromData                          html  
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
*** arch - x64
* MD5 sums
Warning in system(paste(shQuote(ZIP), "-r9Xq", filepath, paste(curPkg, 
collapse = " "))) :
'"zip"' not found
running 'zip' failed
* DONE (simTools)
In R CMD INSTALL
[1] "D:/R/simTools_0.0.0.9000.zip"
```

Comment: I wonder if you are getting a "double quoting". It says `'"zip"'` not found. perhaps it should be `shQuote` around the whole paste? Or no shQuote? I would add that there is already a simTool package in CRAN so your name might be confusing if you plan to release it "in the wild".

Comment: That would be odd as I am just executing the devtools package command build (the exact code submitted was  build ("../simTools", binary=TRUE) which I presume has been tested! (I am following Sams Teach yourself R in 24 hours so I have no plans to actually publish package!)

Comment: Might have been tested on a different OS. The behavior of `shQuote` is not the same across OSes.

Comment: I am using the x64 build on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. Any more ideas of how to fix this? I tried to look at the underlying code of devtools but the .R file just contains a database loader which I can't seem to access.

The ShQuote function needs two arguments according to all the doucmentation I can see in R? The above invocation only seems to have 1.

Comment: I'm getting this error from the command line - R CMD INSTALL --build

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that `zip` is referring to the Linux `zip` command and not the **zip** package.

Do you have [R-tools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) installed? That includes a number of Linux commands and is necessary for building packages on Windows. It also needs to be included to your PATH (System Properties -> Environment Variables). You can check if it is properly set up using `devtools::find_rtools()`.

Comment: The link (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) has the necessary information to solve the problem. Thank you for the tip.